# Switch off Old Number otf feature for line numbering in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, line-numbering

I am using OldNumber features in my presentations, because I like them (de gustibus…). However they look quite odd when used to number lines. What should I do to have lines numbered the standard way while onum still on in the text? I bet there is something to do with the `setuplinenumbering` `conversion` option, but I don't know, how can I connect it to the `feature` command.

```
%\setuplinenumbering[conversion=number]
\definefontfeature [default] [onum=yes]
\definefontfeature [f:lnum] [onum=no]
\starttext
0123456789

\feature[f:lnum] %does not have any effect, which wouldn' be exactly what I want btw
\startlinenumbering
\input dawkins
\stoplinenumbering
\stoptext
```

NB: The `onum` feature could be changed before `startlinenumbering`. I tried to play with it, but without success. And I would like the text to keep its Old Number Style, so this would be a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should never completely override the `default` featureset. It is better to extend it using:

```
\definefontfeature [default] [default] [onum=yes]
```

Then define a `f:lnum` feature that disables the `onum` feature **and enables the `lnum` feature**:

```
\definefontfeature [f:lnum]  [default] [onum=no, lnum=yes]
```

This feature can then be used as:

```
{\feature[+][f:lnum] 0123456789}
```

To enable this feature for linenumbering, use the `style` key (I also added `align=flushright`)

```
\setuplinenumbering[align=flushright,style={\feature[+][f:lnum]}]
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\definefontfeature [default] [default] [onum=yes]
\definefontfeature [f:lnum]  [default] [onum=no, lnum=yes]

\setuplinenumbering[align=flushright,style={\feature[+][f:lnum]}]

\starttext

\startlinenumbering
\input dawkins
\stoplinenumbering
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]